# Json files are not fully inserting into SQLite Database when going over a certain batch size

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

For this android project I'm taking in about 45 tables from SQL Server and converting it to a JSON file to be inserted into the local database on my phone. The only problem is one of these 45 tables has 30,000+ records and it's increasing the insertion time by minutes.

I've tried increasing the batch size, the amount of lines it takes at one time, to 5000 but most of my data from the previously mentioned table is not being inserted all the way. A batch size of 3750 works just fine, but I experience data loss once I hit a size of 4100. My default batch size was 250... Is there a logical explanation for this?

Comment: The logical explanation is that inserting 30.000 records in a single table + rows from other 44 tables in a mobile database is not the best thing in the world to do. Try to split this massive insert operations in a lot of small chunks, probably you are hitting a memory limit somewhere

Comment: SQLite itself has no such limit. This is likely to be a bug in your code.

Comment: FWIW [SQLite's default implementation limits](https://sqlite.org/limits.html) allow 10^9 bytes in a string or blob, 2000 columns in a table, 10^6 bytes in an SQL statement, 64 tables in a JOIN, etc.